# How to add prefix to an Observable column value using map() operator?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, observable

I have an Observable value returned from a service method and I want to add a prefix e.g. 'Prof' as a prefix using `map()` operator.

My method that returns Observable is:

```
list(): Observable<EmployeesDto> { 
    items: Employees;
    ...
}
```

And here is the approach that I try to map data and assign it:

```
...
employeeList : EmployeesDto;

this.service.list()
.pipe(
  map((list: EmployeesDto) => {
    list.items.forEach(m => {
      m.Name = 'Dr.' + m.Name
    });
    this.employeeList = list; // the code does not hit there and cannot set data
  })
)
```

But the problem is that I cannot set employeeList. So, what is the problem with this implementation?

**Update:**
At last step I tessted by using this approach:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

import { of, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  employees$: Observable<any[]>;
  employeesDto$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeData();
  }

  initializeData(): void {
    // this.employees$ = this.getMockEmployees().pipe(
    //   map(list => list.map(item => ({ ...item, name: `Dr. ${item.name}` })))
    // );

    this.employees$ = this.getMockEmployeesDto().pipe(
      map(list => list.map(item => ({ ...item, name: `Dr. ${item.name}` })))
    )
    .subscribe(list => {
      console.log(list);
    }
    )
  }

  getMockEmployees(): Observable<any[]> {
    const employees = [
      {
        name: "Ariana",
        age: 1
      },
      {
        name: "Tom",
        age: 2
      },
      {
        name: "Justin",
        age: 3
      }
    ];

    return of(employees);
  }

  getMockEmployeesDto(): Observable<any[]> {
    const employees$: Observable<any[]>;

    const employeesDto = [
      {
        name: "Ariana",
        age: 1
      },
      {
        name: "Tom",
        age: 2
      },
      {
        name: "Justin",
        age: 3
      }
    ];

    return of(employeesDto);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share some sample

Comment: Sorry, but I am just wondering if the implementation above is correct or not? Do I need to get the result after `.pipe()` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this instead:

```
this.service
  .list()
  .pipe(
    map((list: EmployeesDto) => list.map(item => ({...item, Name: `Dr. ${item.Name}`})))
  )
  .subscribe(list => this.employeeList = list);
```

Have also created a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-prefix-map?file=src/app/app.module.ts)** for your reference

Comment: How can I set `this.employeeList` as `this.employeeList = list` in your answer?

Comment: @PragDopravy No problem, have updated my answer. You can do so on subscribe or you can also have it the same as on the stackblitz demo. Let me know if all is well on your side :)

Comment: Many thanks for your helps. I have just a little problem: the `map` method returns list.items, but I need to return list so that it also contains extra parameters and then set my variable. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi @PragDopravy, would it be possible if you can post a sample data that I can process through? just 2 items would be enough :)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot save it and added to update. I should explain a little bit: There are 2 tables; Employees and EmployeesDto. EmployeesDto contains Employees as `items`. So, when I subscribe to my service method I get EmployeesDto and of course inside it the Employees is also available. Then I want to map a columns in Employees. There is no problem until this point. **But**, after that I need to replace the updated Employees with the firstl retrieved EmployeesDto.Employees. How can I do this? I mean I just want to get EmployeesDto (that contains Employees) and then just update Employees in these

Comment: Hi @PragDopravy, i have updated the stackblitz demo link, may i know if it's what you expect it to be? or if i have missed something? would like to be guided :) Have updated the mock data and the map logic